# Regex group next to another group in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

How would I get the regex of just words (a-z,A-Z,0-9) that is right after another regex group? For example,

**AAFS142** American Literature    3    I don't want this to be read!

**AAFS209** American Music   3   I don't want this to be read

I have [A-Z]{4}\d{3}\b for the bolded part. Now how would I be able to make a regex for American Literature and American Music based strictly on the fact that it is after the other regex?

This is what the regex should catch (in bold).

AAFS142 **American Literature**    3    I don't want this to be read!

AAFS209 **American Music**   3   I don't want this to be read

Comment: Ever heard of a lookbehind?

Comment: Please provide more examples, expected inputs and outputs and the programming language used.

Comment: You can just add `.*` to the end of your pattern to include anything that comes after it. I get the feeling that isn't exactly what you want, but your question was a bit vague.

Comment: `([A-Z]{4}\d{3})\s+(\w+\s+\w+)`? Using positive lookbehind `(?<=[A-Z]{4}\d{3}\s)(\w+\s+\w+)`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Not in JavaScript.

Comment: John, please explain what the trailing boundary is for the expected match. I was going to post https://jsfiddle.net/7prrL25k/, but you mentioned there may also be digits in the expected match.

Answer (score 0):

One way to work around JS's lack of lookbehind is to use non-capturing `(?: )` and capturing groups `()`. Non-capturing groups are matched but not 'remembered', and capturing groups are stored.

As it is with regex, the following is a little dense, but you can see there are three sets of parentheses - a non-capturing, a capturing, and then a non-capturing:

`let regexString = /(?:[A-Z]{4}[\d]{3}\s)([A-za-z0-9 ]+)(?:\s\d)/g`

The first non-captured group `(?:[A-Z]{4}[\d]{3}\s)` matches but doesn't remember the course alphanumeric code. The second `([A-za-z0-9 ]+)` matches and captures any list of `A-Za-z0-9` characters at least once `+` in the `()` – i.e. the title. The last tells it to stop matching for the space+'3' with `(?:\s\d)`.

The second issue with capturing groups and javascript is that they are only returned when you use `regexString.exec()`, and not when you use `.match()`. `.exec()` returns an array, with the matched text as the zeroth (not what is wanted here as it includes the non-capturing groups), and then the subsequent indices are capturing groups.

`let match1 = x.exec('AAFS209 American Music 3')[1]` = `'American Music'`.

`let match2 = x.exec('AAFS241 3D American Musical Theatre 3')[1]` = `'3D American Musical Theatre'`. (Not sure if that is a course, let alone a thing, but one can hope. Also, wanted to make the regex worked with digits in the title).